# How to add OpenGL library in CLion?

Tags: opengl, cmake, clion

I have a folder named `GL` containing following files:

```
---glu32.dll
---GLAux.h
---OPENGL32.LIB
---glut32.lib
---glut.h
---GL.H
---glui.h
---glui32.lib
---glut32.dll
---GLU32.LIB
---Glaux.lib
---GLU.H
---opengl32.dll
```

I have worked with these files in Visual Studio but I am new to CLion that's why don't know how the linking directory works through CMake. How can I use the liraries in CLion?

Comment: Is this just a general "How do I link libraries in CLion" question?

Comment: quite similar to that. I have tried the instructions from this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206558149-How-do-I-add-my-libraries-to-the-project-  but it's not working for me. Usually the library comes with many files but i want to use only these that's why i made separate directory and trying to add in clion. i don't understand what am I missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by adding the following lines in the CMake file

```
include_directories(GL)

target_link_libraries(OpenGL GL/Glaux.lib GL/GLU32.LIB GL/glui32.lib GL/glut32.lib GL/OPENGL32.LIB)
```

Answer (score 8):

I have made it work in both Windows 10 and Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) after a lot of searching on Google. Apparently it's not so easy to find after all. So, I am gonna put an end to this problem now and here.

Here, I am going to show you how to configure the CMakeLists.txt file to compile a OpenGL program which is the main challenge here. I am assuming that you can write basic OpenGL programs and you have written a file named 
'demoMain.cpp'.

### For Windows

I am assuming you can setup OpenGL on windows. If you can't, there are plenty of tutorials on youtube and StackOverflow. After that, continue.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Graphics_Offline_1) # Your Project Name

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(OpenGL)
include_directories(OpenGL/include) # OpenGL/include has to contain the required OpenGL's .h files
include_directories(OpenGL/lib) # OpenGL/lib has to contain the required OpenGL's .lib files


# glut32.dll must be present in "project-directory/OpenGL/dll/"


add_custom_target(glutdlllib
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenGL/dll/glut32.dll ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )

# required .lib files to be copied into compiler's proper directory
set(OpenGlLibs glaux glu32 glui32 glut32 opengl32)


#These 3 lines are just linking and making executables

add_executable(demo demoMain.cpp)

target_link_libraries(demo ${OpenGlLibs})

add_dependencies(demo glutdlllib)
```

### For Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

It should work for other Ubuntu versions too. Linux has made it easier to use OpenGL than Windows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10) # common to every CLion project
project(OpenGLLinuxTest) # project name


set(OpenGlLinkers -lglut -lGLU -lGL) # setting all the Glut libraries as one variable.


################################################

add_executable(OpenGLLinuxTest1 main.cpp ) #common to all clion project
target_link_libraries(OpenGLLinuxTest1 ${OpenGlLinkers}) # linking opengl libraries to the project

#################################################
```

I am assuming that you can install OpenGL on Ubuntu. If you are facing problem with that,

> follow this link -
>   http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-opengl-ubuntu-linux/ .
>   If this is not working, follow this one -
>   https://gist.github.com/shamiul94/a632f7ab94cf389e08efd7174335df1c

Answer (score 0):

this is a template: https://github.com/longshilin/Clion-OpenGL
use clion to build opengl on Windows and MacOS.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Clion-OpenGL) # Your Project Name

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES OpenGL/src/Application.cpp)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLFW/include)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLFW/lib-vc2019)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/include)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/lib/Release/Win32)

add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)

add_executable(Clion-OpenGL ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Clion-OpenGL glew32s glfw3 opengl32 User32 Gdi32 Shell32)
```